# How to add next numbers to string in JavaScript

Tags: jquery

On button click, i want to take last part of the url, and replace last segment string with one number higher. For example from img15.jpg to img16.jpg. Following code is saving last part of the url, but i am not sure how to iterate number.

```
$('.next').on('click',function(){
        parts = modalContainer.find('img').attr('src');
        array = parts.split('/');

        lastsegment = array[array.length-1];

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Substring function to get just the number in your example would be "15" and then use replace function to replace that number with the number+1.

```
var str = "img15.jpg";
var res = str.substring(3,str.length-4);
alert('new file is: ' + str.replace(res,parseInt(res)+1));
```

Take into account that in the substring you need to know the length of the file (for know where to start), for example "img" has 3 characters, then you are going to finish in the length of the string minous 4 because of the dot and extension of the file, for example ".jpg" has 4 characters.

Here you have a jsfiddle with an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/6xdaenom/1/

Comment: Thanks mate, it is work, and file name is static so it wont be a problem. Solved

Answer (score 0):

The result is String

if you +1 directly like this(if lastsegment is 15)

```
lastsegment+=1 //return 151
```

So use parseInt convert String to Int

```
parseInt(lastsegment)+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use REGEX to match the pattern and capture the digit in a group. Then increment the number and replace it with the original value.

Check the below code snippet.

```js
function getUrl() {
  var url = "https://somewebsite.com/images/sunrise1.jpg";
  return url;
}

function getNextUrl(url) {
  var regex = /(\S+)(\d+)(\.\w+)$/g;
  var match = regex.exec(url);
  var number = parseInt(match[2]);  
  number++;
  regex.lastIndex = 0;
  var nextUrl = url.replace(regex, "$1" + number + "$3");
  return nextUrl;
}

var url = getUrl();
var nextUrl = getNextUrl(url)
console.log(nextUrl)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastsegment = 'img_or_whatever15.jpg';
var nextSegment = lastsegment .replace(/(\d+)/,function (g) {
  return parseInt(g)+1;
});
```